# Transfer folder from local machine to Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

What is the easiest way to transfer a directory with sub-directories from your local machine to an Azure VM?

Comment: Local Machine: right click copy  Azure VM: Right click paste

Comment: This is a question better suited for SuperUser, as it is not programming-related.

Comment: @Sorceri Dude, you need to submit an answer. your comment literally saved my day here LOL, i cant believe ive been spending hours and all i needed to do was the ol' copy/paste method!

Answer (score -1):

You can transfer files on your virtual machine using FTP. You need to setup FTP server on Azure VM. Please follow these steps:

1. Download [Filezilla FTP Server](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) and install it on your VM.
2. Once its installed [Setup a server connection](https://it.cornell.edu/managed-servers/transfer-files-using-filezilla#section-1).
3. Now download [Filezilla Client Application](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) and install on your local machine.
4. Once its installed [Transfer files to VM](https://it.cornell.edu/managed-servers/transfer-files-using-filezilla#section-2).

This is the most secure and fastest way to transfer files on remote locations.

Comment: ftp is definitely *not* the most secure way to transfer files, nor is it the fastest.